# SQLite select record where a value is within a string

Tags: sqlite, sql

I have a DB structured like this:

**TABLE1**

```
(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,

titolo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

autore VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

id_categoria VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,

testo TEXT,

UNIQUE(titolo,autore))
```

**TABLE2**

```
(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,

titolo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,

attiva INTEGER(1) DEFAULT(0))
```

How can I select a row where **table2._id** is within **table1.id_categoria**?

Tthe **table1.id_categoria** field is something like this "1-2-3-..." I want to check if the integer field _id of table2 is in field string id_categoria of table1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select table2.*,table1.id_categoria from table1,table2 
where table1._id=table2._id and 
instr(table1.id_categoria, table2._id)
```

[image: Check this:]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table2 JOIN table1 ON "-"||table1.id_categoria||"-" LIKE "%-"||table2._id||"-%";
```

Answer (score 0):

LS-dev thats not correct answer.... see the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Makes no sense! In SQLite it works. Try `WHERE` instead of `ON`.

Comment: Ok, you are using MySQL. In MySQL, `||` is by default `OR` operator. You must enable [PIPES_AS_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html). By the way, correct your tags, this is not SQLite.

Answer (score -1):

Locate function in mysql works fine, you can experiment it with join queries with following example:

```
select * from table1,table2 where locate(table2._id,table1.id_categoria)
```

For the join perspective, you can also use something like

```
select * from table1,table2 where 
locate(table2._id,table1.id_categoria) and 
table1.titolo=table2.titolo
```

Comment: Try this: select * from table1,table2 where '-'+table2._id+'-' like table1.id_categoria

Comment: i don't think that this is the solution. example: if `table2._id` is 3 and `table1.id_categoria` is "1,3,4,7" does the select return always 0 rows?